# Creating and modifying a branch on the server using the push command

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push

Consider the following scenario w.r.t. an existing repository. This is the first time a new branch has been created in this repository, and I am and have always been the only user.

1. `git branch feature`
2. `git checkout feature`
3. Various changes to existing files.
4. `git add -u`
5. `git commit -m "Added a feature."`
6. `git push`

Does the last command create a branch in the server? If I repeat steps 3-6, will the changes be added to this branch?

Answer (score 1):

The answer assumes you have a remote repo (can check by: `git remote`).

If you attempt to push locally created branch to remote repo, when it doesn't exist there, you'll get:

```
The current branch <branch_name> has no upstream branch
```

You should do:

```
git push --set-upstream origin <branch_name>
```

It will create the branch in remote repo and push the changes.

Once it's created there, you easily can do `push` / `pull` / `fetch` ..

Comment: Thanks. And then I can repeat steps 3-6 (without the `--set-upstream`) to add changes to this branch?

Comment: Why do you need to specify a remote branch? Why can't git figure it out on its own? Isn't it unsafe to allow a user to specify which branch they wish to push the changes to? What if they accidentally or maliciously choose the wrong branch?